# What's the difference between the following two Java lines?

Tags: java

I was given two of these line of code. What are the differences between two of these and which one is better for simple program.

```
public static < E > void swap(List< E > list, int i, int j);
```

vs

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);
```

Comment: "which one is better for simple program." depends on what the simple program needs that method for and what the method does.

Comment: If your method takes something from the list and puts something in the list, then only the first one will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)
```

is how [`Collections.swap`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L494) is declared.

The problem is that `swap` needs to get and set elements from/to the list: specifically, the `set` will fail to compile as-is, because the compiler doesn't know a safe type to allow to be put into to the list - even if it's a thing that it just got out of the list.

If you look in the method body:

```
final List l = list;
l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
```

This is essentially breaking the Java compiler's type checking: it's OK in this case, because we know it's safe to put an element back into the list that we've just taken it out of.  This is a case where we have more knowledge of the types involved, so we take control ourselves (via raw types).

The compiler will complain about you doing this - it can't prove you're doing anything unsafe, but it will create warnings just in case you didn't mean to do so. If you look just above this method signature, you'll find:

```
SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
```

which tells the compiler not to generate that warning.

In general, using raw types/subverting type checking is not a desirable thing to do: the compiler is better at checking things than us, provided it has more information. That's what the first form is: a way to give the compiler more information:

```
public static < E > void swap(List< E > list, int i, int j);
```

The extra information comes from the type variable `E`: now the compiler knows that things it gets out are of type `E`, and that it can put things of type `E` back into the list. As such, the swap can be implemented as:

```
l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
```

with no need for the suppressions, no need for raw types.

So, if the first form is better, why is the second form the one that's used in the library? I don't know for sure, but it's likely just "that's the way it was done". You'd have to ask the library designer.

Unfortunately, the two forms are considered different from a method signature perspective, so you can't replace the second form with the first form: you're stuck with it. Ultimately, it doesn't really make a difference from a practical perspective of using that library method.